What am I doing wrong when trying to manually focus an input with Angular and PrimeNg?
I am using Angular with PrimeNg. I have a Google Forms-like app and in a part of the app I have a set of options, each having a radioButton. I can have the 'Other' option where the user can manually input an answer.
I want to have the same effect as in Google Forms where when you click on the radio button of the 'Other' option, the input focuses automatically.
I have a minimal example here where you can see what I have tried: link
I have tried using both @ViewChild() and Renderer2 to select the input and this seems to work fine in selecting the element.
It seems that calling inputRef.nativeElement.focus() does not work.
Am I missing something?

Not really, but the solution provided below worked just fine

We can just call the focus method, when there is a click event on the radio button, example below!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RadioButtonClickEvent, RadioButtonModule } from 'primeng/radiobutton';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RadioButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    InputTextModule,
  ],
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p-radioButton value="1" formControlName="name" (click)="inputRef?.focus();"></p-radioButton>
  <input pInputText #inputRef />
  </form>`,
})
export class App {
  private fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  @ViewChild('inputRef') inputRef!: ElementRef;

  form = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
  });

  onRadioClick(e: RadioButtonClickEvent) {
    this.inputRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks! It seems like the issue was using the onClick event from primeNg rather than the native click
